# unable to edit pg_hba.conf file in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-hba.conf

I want to create a backup of the original pg_hba.conf file (may be as pg_hba.conf.bk) and then add an entry into the existing pg_hba.conf file. So far this is what i've been trying to do, but every time it says permission denied even if i go via root user or use sudo.

My attempt:

```
$ pg_conftool -s 10 main show hba_file
[OUT] /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

$ sudo cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
    [OUT] local   all             postgres                              peer
          local   all             all                                   md5
          host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32          md5
          host    all             all             ::1/128               md5
```

now when i try adding a line into it, i get the permission denied error

```
$ sudo echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
[OUT] bash: /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf: Permission denied
```

This will be a part of deployment script therefore, I can't really go and make the entry into the pg_hba.conf manually. So, how can i make an entry into the conf file?

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote your command, the redirection `>>` will be *outside* the `sudo` command, so it is executed with the permissions of the normal user. Hence the error message.

Try this command line:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >> /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf'
```

Comment: you mean like this `sudo 'echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust" >>/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf'` ?? because this didn't work. could you please exemplify the same..